# How to properly annotate a class instance

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, typechecking, python-typing

I was reading through the [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) documentation and I was wondering what is the proper way to annotate a class instance.

I have not found the answer in the documentation.

I have the following module:

```py
class global_variables:
     # Class body

global_variables_dictionary: global_variables = global_variables("application.yaml")
```

Is `something: <class_name> = class_name()` the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: the *same way you annotate anything*, **everything** is a class instance in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Btw. you should avoid naming classes with the lowercase. You should use camel case instead regarding to PEP:

> Start each word with a capital letter. Do not separate words with
> underscores. This style is called camel case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct way, but class name shouldn't be in lowercase in my opinion.

Comment: It's not only your opinion, i.e. [PEP 8 -- Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).